# How do I determine where I can get from the city by car?

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, graph, maps

How do I determine where I can get to from the city (say New York) for 2 hours (can change) by car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a graph :

- each edge is a road
- each vertex is a city

Second Give a weight to each road = weight is the time from one city to another using this edge considering traffic etc...

Use Dijkstra's algorithm for example to calculate the min distance between 2 cities

Finally chose all the one with a weight less than 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

I found Google Distance Matrix API.
It's kind of what should be )